# Core data - selecting which xcdatamodel to use

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I'm working on an app and need to make an update to the xcdatamodel file.

So I created a new file:

I have model.xcdatamodel
and now I have model2.xcdatamodel

However, it looks like the app is still using model.xcdatamodel. How can I change that to point to model2.xcdatamodel?
I see that next to model.xcdatamodel, there is a "green check icon".

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Ah I got it. Just need to select model.xcdatamodeld (i.e the parent of all xcdatamodel files) and change the "Versioned core data model" to the one you want to use.

Comment: Where is "Versioned core data model" located?

Comment: A screenie of this in XCode 5 would be nice!